# LiteDb performance and limitation for production high data volume

Tags: performance, production-environment, throughput, litedb

I would like to know if anyone has experiece in using LiteDB for high volume data stream application on producution environment.
What are its limitations and its pros? Or why it sould be preferred to MongoDB.

My particular use case requires to handle a high level throughput of feeds which should be used to update documents representing for example odds for a live sport event (sportsbook). The odds can be thousands for one single match and matches can be thousand as well.

Updating them fast is a strong requirement.

thank you for your help